# Touchbar Backlight Stopped Working

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

My MacBook pro 2017 15 inch touchbar model stopped turning the backlight of the touchbar. The functionality is still there as it still works when touched. I have tried factory resetting, smc reset, nvram reset but it had no effect on the display.

Any more things to try would be greatly helpful as I am out of options and the warranty has expired a month ago.

Comment: Contact Apple. It's only a little out of warranty so they might fix it for free (or a small price).

Comment: @fsb I will head to apple tomorrow but from what i researched is that they dont just replace the touchbar, but they replace the entire top assembly including keyboard, battery and trackpad.

Comment: True. You can also initiate a chat with them to see if they'll fix it for free before you go to Apple.

Comment: @fsb Yeah thats a better approach as it wasn't accidental damage.